# Does my Google Apps Script in my Google Sheet have to request my data each time the Sheet opens?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

I have a project that I've been working on which uses the Google Places API and pulls data about a specified place.

I am still learning about the functions of Google Cloud Platform as I quickly ran through my free $300 trial credit. I had hoped that my simple use case would not go through that all so quickly, but it appears that it made 62,000 requests in the one month that I used it.

**I have noticed that every time I open my Google Sheet, while the Sheet has data in it already, it appears to re-request the data, presumably using up my allotted requests.**

**Is there a way to modify my code or a setting somewhere so that once data is pulled into the Sheet it does not have to pull it again unless I do so manually?**

Or is my understanding of what's happening here mistaken? Should I be looking to fix this some other way?

As a side note, eventually I want to build in functionality so that I can use a custom UI button to trigger the scripts to run all over and change the color of the cell or something on ones where changes happened (eg. if business hours change, the cell turns yellow so I know to update my Google MyMap for that one detail. And then if I ran the function from the UI button again, that same hours cell would change to normal/no color fill as there had been no change since the last time the function was run), but I am not sure if this is the appropriate time to implement that change.

Below is my code:

```
// This location basis is used to narrow the search -- e.g. if you were
// building a sheet of bars in NYC, you would want to set it to coordinates
// in NYC.
// You can get this from the url of a Google Maps search.
const LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON = "43.17272951663479, 16.44381364713987"; // e.g. "37.7644856,-122.4472203"

function COMBINED2(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    place.name,
    place.formatted_address,
    place.formatted_phone_number,
    place.website,
    place.url,
    weekdays.trim(),
  
  ] ];

  return data;
}

function GPS(text) {

   //TEST PARSING
     var API_KEY = 'AIxxxxyD1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxGKlrE';
    var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
    var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
    var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

    var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
    var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
    var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
    
    var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2); 
    var content = responseAPI.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content.toString()); //Sample JSON parsing

    //An array variable to contain the longitude and latitude data
    var inputArray = []; 
    //Parse the "location" JSON array contents
    var gpsCoord = json.result.geometry.location

    //Place the JSON contents into the array variable
    for (var j in gpsCoord){ 
      inputArray.push([gpsCoord[j]]); 
    }
    return inputArray.join(", "); 


}

function name(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    place.name   
  
  ] ];

  return data;
}

function address2(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    place.formatted_address      
  ] ];

  return data;
}

function phone(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    place.formatted_phone_number

  ] ];

  return data;
}

function website(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    place.website
      
  ] ];

  return data;
}

function maps(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    place.url
   
  ] ];

  return data;
}

function hours(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxE';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    weekdays.trim(),
  
  ] ];

  return data;
}
```

Comment: You need to use what's called the Proxy Design Pattern. Before you do, make sure you are comfortable with Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript. I have [an article on Geek Culture](https://medium.com/geekculture/using-design-patterns-in-google-apps-script-ceaa7606d2d6?sk=fc97b1ecb43c8a8aaef739aafe1e30c5) that walks through the use of design patterns in Google Apps Script including the Proxy Design Pattern to solve a similar issue.

Comment: I wondered about this the last time you asked this question or perhaps this is the same question.  But I guess now that you using this function in as cell formula.  So every cell is making a call every time the sheet gets updated.  Personally, I never use cell functions if I can avoid it.  And in this case I'd just run the function when I want to update the sheet and I'd try to write it so that in can make incremental changes depending upon my requirements.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk - Am I just looking to integrate that one Proxy Design Pattern section into my code somehow? I'm not a coder/programmer, just stitched this together from other projects and some help, but at least I have a direction and terminology for what it is that I need to do.

Comment: @Cooper - I guess that makes sense why my number of calls was so high. Five requests for a running list of places adds up every time I load the Sheet... Is there a setting to only run the function when I want to update the Sheet? Or a line of code to accomplish this?

Comment: @JeffAbrahams design patterns do take some skills to use. As an alternative you may want to include a test so that your function only fetches data when no value is present if it fits your purpose. That would be simpler.

Comment: I don't think so but like I haven't used a cell function in a project for 3 years so I don't really know.