# How can I make my function run only if there is no fetched data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-places-api

I have a Google Apps Script project where I am able to enter the name of a location in Column A of a Google Sheet and have several aspects fetched using the Google Places API. I have been working on this [for a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651671/does-my-google-apps-script-in-my-google-sheet-have-to-request-my-data-each-time), and my most recent revision seeks to solve an issue where my function was making too many requests, causing me to burn through the free $200 in credit on the Google Cloud platform.

I noted that every time I opened my Google Sheet, it would have to fetch all of the data again, burning through even more requests just to find information it had already located.

What would be my best bet in order to fetch all of the information and keep it in my Sheet so that it does not make a new request for information every time the Sheet gets opened? Just an If statement to check if there is a value already in one of the cells which gets filled in once the function gets run?

Below is my code. Right now, I just run =COMINED2(A2) in Cell B2 to fetch the information for the place in A2 and that gets placed in B2, C2, D2, E2, etc. Happy to reconfigure things if people have other suggestions?

```
function COMBINED2(text) {
  var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyvxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQ';
  var baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json';
  var queryUrl = baseUrl + '?input=' + text + '&inputtype=textquery&key=' + API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var placeId = JSON.parse(json);
  var ID = placeId.candidates[0].place_id;

  var fields = 'name,geometry,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number,website,url,types,opening_hours';
  var baseUrl2 = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=';
  var queryUrl2 = baseUrl2 + ID + '&fields=' + fields + '&key='+ API_KEY + "&locationbias=point:" + LOC_BASIS_LAT_LON;

  if (ID == '') {
    return 'Give me a Google Places URL...';
  }

  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl2);
  var json2 = response2.getContentText();
  var place = JSON.parse(json2).result;

  var placeName = place.name;
  var placeAddress = place.formatted_address;
  var placePhoneNumber = place.formatted_phone_number;
  var placeWebsite = place.website;
  var placeURL = place.url;  

  var weekdays = '';
  place.opening_hours.weekday_text.forEach((weekdayText) => {
    weekdays += ( weekdayText + '\r\n' );
  } );

  var data = [ [
    place.name,
    place.formatted_address,
    place.formatted_phone_number,
    place.website,
    place.url,
    weekdays.trim(),
  
  ] ];

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a custom formula will work in your case since custom formulas are supposed to be independent of range, i.e, it should not check a **specific** cell or range whether it has value or not.

You would be better off creating a regular Apps Script function that calls `COMBINED2`, and either triggering it manually using the script UI, or probably assigning it to a button.

```
// this function calls COMBINED2()
function call_COMBINED2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var text = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var data = COMBINED2(text);
  var dest = ss.getRange("B2:G2");
  dest.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: It is interesting that you suggest that because it kind of heads in the direction I had ultimately hoped to go with this project. I am making these Sheets to log the number of places I have been recommended or researched/vetted for travel. After these trips and over time, these Sheets become outdated. I had hoped to create a button which would refresh the whole sheet and maybe change the color of a cell when it updated information different than what was in there already. Is that kind of in line with what capability you are suggesting? Or should I be doing something bigger to accomplish that?

Comment: Much like that. In any case, it is generally not a good idea to use custom formulas to execute Google API's.